In a react relay query definition, How to add @connection directive to a graphql field that expects a union
Consider a schema as below where the field accepting connection is a UNION.
type OnlineCourse @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  url: String!
}

type OnlineCourseEdge {
  cursor: String!
  node: OnlineCourse
}

type OnlineCourseConnection {
  edges: [OnlineCourseEdge]
  pageInfo: PageInfo
}

type Error{
  type: String
  message: String
  location: String
}

union URecentCourse = OnlineCourseConnection | Error

type PageInfo {
  endCursor: String
  hasNextPage: Boolean
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  recentCourses: [URecentCourse] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type Query {
  getUser(id: ID!): User
}

I tried a series of combinations but all throw an error including the below
query GetUserRecentCourses($id: ID!, $after: String, $first: Int) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    id
    name
    recentCourses(first: $first, after: $after) @connection(key: "byUser") {
      ... on OnlineCourseConnection {
        edges {
          cursor
          node {
            id
            title
            url
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
      }
      ... on Error {
        type            
        message
        location
      }
    }
  }
}

Also tried
query GetUserRecentCourses($id: ID!, $after: String, $first: Int) {
      getUser(id: $id) {
        id
        name
        recentCourses(first: $first, after: $after) {
          ... on OnlineCourseConnection @connection(key: "byUser"){
            edges {
              cursor
              node {
                id
                title
                url
              }
            }
            pageInfo {
              endCursor
              hasNextPage
            }
          }
          ... on Error {
            type            
            message
            location
          }
        }
      }
    }

Note: I know I can remove the union or nest a field which only expects connection, but the question is to know how to do it "with a union"
